# How do I reposition VS Code's pop-up suggestion box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, the pop-up suggestion box overlaps the lines below where I'm typing.

If I'm looking at said lines, having the box obstruct what I'm trying to look at is not helpful.

Is there a way to reposition the suggestion box? Like, to force the box on the right-side of the screen, rather than appear at my caret?

I've tried searching Visual Studio Code's settings, but have not had any luck.

Comment: in Visual Studio you can make it transparent by pressing `Ctrl` key or `Alt` key, you can add a feature request for this